# How to get an object custom property within Geometry Nodes (without the creation of drivers)?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

How to access custom object properties within  *Geometry Nodes* without using drivers?
In the *Shader Editor* this can be easily accomplished by adding an "Attribute" node e.g.:

[image: Shader editor custom attribute]

Note that the geometry being edited will be linked to other geometries each with different values in the custom property.

---

@quellenform thank you for your comment, I tried with *Named Attribute* but it does not output what I meant to output (a value of 1000 in my case based on the TOT35 custom property), did I miss something? please see below:

[image: Example]

Appreciate any heads-up

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! The node `Named Attribute` is your friend in this case.

Comment: @quellenform thank you for your comment, I added a comment 'as answer' below.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake, you are talking about "Custom Properties", not "Attributes". In the case of custom properties, I'm afraid there is currently no other solution, because they are not directly related to any geometry (points, faces, edges, etc.)

Comment: But why don't you control this directly via a group input in *Geometry Nodes*? Do you really need custom properties here? Tell us more about what exactly you want to do, maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Those geometries have been imported via the BlenderGIS plugin along with custom data from GIS data (spatial data). I need to get these "Custom Properties" information in the geometry node editor to extrude each polygon based on each geometry's "Custom Property" that in my case represent the height or Z values...

Comment: Then how about a Python script that rewrites the custom properties into the attributes of the mesh into the face domain for you?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, perhaps given that a python script seems the only option in this case, could you please provide an example? I think it will be really beneficial for the community!